# How to solve this differential equation $ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -4 + x $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a problem from my book but I'm stuck.

$$
\frac{d^2x}{d t^2} = -4 + x
$$

I suspect it might involve `\sin` or `\cos` because I have solved other similar problems that way, but the constant makes it harder.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $
\dfrac{d^2x}{d t^2} = x\,$?

Comment: First solve $x''-x=0$, that gets you the homogeneous solution..  Then find a particular solution for $x''-x=4$,  here you will be guessing your solution looks like a polynomial of degree 0.  Add the two.

Comment: $\textbf{HINT}$ Multiply both sides by $x'$ and integrate.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know one solution is $e^t$ but I haven't reached the chapter for the exponential derivative yet. So it's a bit weird. The other equations I have solved were more like $d^2x/dt^2 = -x $, which can be solved with $x = sin(t)$.

Comment: another solution is $x=e^{-t}$

Comment: If you let $y=x-4$ and solve for $y$ (homogeneous form), you'll be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x''-x=-4$. $4$ is the $g(x)$ Thing. You can find the homogenous solution first to
$x''-x=0$ This will be of form $e^{\lambda t}$. Plugging it in you get $\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}-e^{\lambda t}=0$, dividing by $e^{\lambda t}$ you get $\lambda^2-1=0$. Solving this you get $\lambda=\pm1$, so the solution is $c_1e^{1t}+c_2e^{-1t}$. For the particular solution, you look at a table, its a constant, substituting $A$ for the particular guess, you get $-A=-4\Rightarrow A=4$ you just add $4$ to the homogenous solution.

Final solution is $c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+4$. Indeed if you take the second derivative you have $$x''=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}=(c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+4)-4=x-4$$ Here is example of a table for future reference if you need, or just google "particular solution table" https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qiE_mLjXhXM/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: That table is useful, thanks